# Random error when integrating jquery/angular/kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

It's very strange, but I keep obtaining this error, but not regularly, on the same page:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/modulerr?p0=AngularApp&p1=Erro…Ob%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A60303%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A435)

If I realod the page with F5 (or Ctrl/F5) sometimes it happens, sometimes not.

I'm using an empty HTML page, where I only load
- jquery-2.1.1.min.js
- angular.min.js (1.3.10)
- kendo.all.min.js (v2014.3.1119)

It's really strange: I don't know what else to add, to help you in understanding my situation... :-(

Thanks in advance, please ask me what can help...

### UPDATE

If I strip out even the module definitions, I get another very strange behaviour.
Right now the relevant code is just:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Kendo/cultures/kendo.culture.it-IT.min.js"></script>
```

No module definitions, no html, nothing.
If I load the page with IE or FF, I always get no errors, but with Chrome I get one time no errors and one time 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function           kendo.all.min.js:50', totally regularly (if I get no errors, I reaload the page and there is the error, I reload the page and get no errors... and so on!).
If I reload the page with Ctrl-F5, I always get the error!
If I comment out the angular script, it's always ok!
I'm quite sure that I never found an error like this... :-(

Comment: Could you post your angular module definition?  It sounds like you might be missing the kendo dependencies.

Comment: Please, read my update: I have strange behaviours, only in Chrome, just including angular in a void kendo mvc application...

Comment: I have a feeling that because there's no module defined and you're including Angular and Kendo (which has its directives in that file), it's unhappy about those 2 being referenced.  Do you plan on using them together at all?

Comment: Of course yes, but I have tried created a whole page, and in every combination, I always get (different and random) errors. I suspected something cache related, but it shouldn't be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really stupid! :-(
I have a stack of inclusions, and I lost control of the fact that I declared ng-app twice... :-( The random error is crazy, but it's all my fault... :-(
Thanks to @mmillican and the people who read my question, I'm really really sorry.